# Publish bookmarks in api google maps from android studio with data stored in a MYSQL database

Tags: android-studio

Publish bookmarks in api google maps from android studio with data stored in a 
How can I publish bookmarks in api google maps from android studio with data stored in a MYSQL database

Comment: "publish bookmarks in api google maps" <-- what does this mean?

Comment: How can I publish bookmarks with the google maps API, using latitude and longitude from a mysql database